# javascript mouseover not registering, but CSS is

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, django-templates

I have a basic page I am trying to show a title for each url on, and I want the url to flash below the title if you hover over. I tried to follow an example here, http://jsfiddle.net/RetMp/963/, and while my CSS is working (it hides the text initially), on mouseover, it does nothing. Looking at that jsfiddle example, it seems it should work. The template is as such:

```
<head>
    <style>
    #article-link .url-text {
    position:relative;
    visibility:hidden;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('.hover').mouseover(function() {
                $('.url-text').css("visibility","visible");
            });

            $('.hover').mouseout(function() {
                $('.url-text').css("visibility","hidden");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>



{% if active_articles %}
{% for article in active_articles %}
    <div id="article-link">
        <p class="hover">
            <span><a href="http://{{ article.url }}">{{ article.title }}</a></span>    <a href="{% url 'index:delete-article' article.id %}">Delete</a>
        </p><p class="url-text">{{ article.url }}</p>
    </div>

{% endfor %}
<br/>
<a href="{% url 'index:new-article' %}"><p>Add a new article to read</p></a>
{% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'index:new-article' %}"><p>Go make some articles!</p></a>
{% endif %}
```

The html generated (view page source) is:

```
<!-- http://jsfiddle.net/RetMp/963/ -->


<head>
    <style>
    #article-link .url-text {
    position:relative;
    visibility:hidden;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('.hover').mouseover(function() {
                $('.url-text').css("visibility","visible");
            });

            $('.hover').mouseout(function() {
                $('.url-text').css("visibility","hidden");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>






        <div id="article-link">
            <p class="hover">
                <span><a href="http://https://mail.google.com/mail/">gmail</a></span>    <a href="/delete-article/1/">Delete</a>
            </p><p class="url-text">https://mail.google.com/mail/</p>
        </div>


    <br/>
    <a href="/new-article/"><p>Add a new article to read</p></a>
```

Why doesn't mouseover make the text visible in this case? Thank you

Comment: can you copy-paste the generated HTML from the django-template engine and share with us in your question, because i can see there are multiple if conditions which might restrict certain parts of template from being rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include jquery separately and then attach mouseover and mouseout event on window ready.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.hover').mouseover(function() {
            $('.url-text').css("visibility","visible");
        });

        $('.hover').mouseout(function() {
            $('.url-text').css("visibility","hidden");
        });
    });
</script>
```

EDIT
This is a complete html page working:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        #article-link .url-text {
            position: relative;
            visibility: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="article-link">
         <p class="hover">
            <span><a href="http://https://mail.google.com/mail/">gmail</a></span>
            <a href="/delete-article/1/">Delete</a>
        </p>
        <p class="url-text">https://mail.google.com/mail/</p>
    </div>

    <br/>
    <a href="/new-article/"><p>Add a new article to read</p></a>
    <script>
        $('.hover').mouseover(function() {
            $('.url-text').css("visibility","visible");
        });

        $('.hover').mouseout(function() {
            $('.url-text').css("visibility","hidden");
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. That's not "on window load." 2. Using `ready` (or its shortcut `$(function() { ... });`) is for when you don't control where the script tags go. When you do, just put them at the end of the document, instead of using `ready`.

Comment: I just started learning javascript. I moved the entire javascript to the bottom, my coworker said that helps it load without stalling the page too. Nothing changed

Comment: I've added a complete html page as example. I'm sorry for the error between window load and ready

Comment: nesting it in `$(function() {....})` or putting it at the end of the html file. That's because file is executed from top to bottom, if you place script before defining `<p class="hover">` event can't be bind because that `p` doesn't exists in dom